# How to import MSN live blog to wordpress.com blog?

Tags: import, blog, wordpress.com

I have my blog at http://vgnam2404.spaces.live.com and I want to move all of the posts (and comments) to my wordpress blog at http://namgivu.wordpress.com. I don't know how to do this. Please help if you know how to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazingly & suprisingly (to me at least) Microsoft have decided to move their Windows Live Space blogger to a "new home": wordpress.com (see official announcement [from Microsoft](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/09/27/wordpress-com-and-windows-live-partnering-together-and-providing-an-upgrade-for-30-million-windows-live-spaces-customers.aspx) and from [Wordpress.com](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/welcome-windows-live-spaces-bloggers/))

So now all are supported by the two big company and I don't have to use other tools. Thank you [`phwd`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/40/phwd) anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no web application to do this.

I have tried using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) to recreate the feed but the data does not parse. If possible you can try scraping the html with the Fetch Page Module. This become a bit hard for pagination. If you are able to reach this far. You will have to get in the WordPress eXtended RSS (WXR) format.

A desktop solution is to use the [Live Space Mover](http://b2.broom9.com/?page_id=519) Python Script (I have read some of your blog posts it seems you are an able coder with perl and the sorts). Now before jumping into this this script, realize it is dated. So I would suggest sitting down and updating it or using the advice given by [Chad Miller](http://sev17.com/2010/03/goodbye-live-spaces-hello-wordpress/) on how he updated the import workflow.